# pandas merge columns within dataframe and overwrite

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge columns within a large dataframe such that values are retained in `col1` but are overwritten if there are values in `col2` or `col3`, to produce result shown in `merged`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['1', 'A','nan','nan'],
                         ['2', 'B','B1','nan'],
                         ['3', 'C','C1','nan'],
                         ['4', 'C','nan','C2'],
                         ['5', 'D','D2','nan'],
                         ['6', 'E','nan','E3']
                         ]
                   , columns=['ObjectID', 'col1', 'col2','col3'])
```

result

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['1', 'A','nan','nan', 'A'],
                         ['2', 'B','B1','nan', 'B1'],
                         ['3', 'C','C1','nan', 'C1'],
                         ['4', 'C','nan','C2', 'C2'],
                         ['5', 'D','D2','nan','D2' ],
                         ['6', 'E','nan','E3', 'E3'],
                         ]
                   , columns=['ObjectID', 'col1', 'col2','col3', 'merged'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.fillna()` with the `ffill` method to fill `nan` with the value from the previous column (`axis=1`) , like below:

```
df['merged'] = df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
```

Output:

> ```
>    ObjectID col1 col2 col3 merged
> 0         1    A  NaN  NaN      A
> 1         2    B   B1  NaN     B1
> 2         3    C   C1  NaN     C1
> 3         4    C  NaN   C2     C2
> 4         5    D   D2  NaN     D2
> 5         6    E  NaN   E3     E3
> ```